# Why assign to $var before return?

Tags: php

I see a lot of people assigning whatever they have to return in a function to a variable before they return the value. Also when they call a function in a function which can directly return the output of the called function they first assign it to a variable, is this really needed ?

```
function ($foo) {

    $bar = $this->otherFunction($foo);

    return $bar;
}
```

instead of:

```
function ($foo) {

    return $this->otherFunction($foo); 

}
```

I have strong believes that returning $foo is only needed if you start or have multiple parts in your code where $foo can be declared and overwritten and you make sure you return as last resort.

I'm not able to find a satisfying answer about it.

Comment: I think this, like many other things, is purely down to personal preference and coding style. I'd suggest following the [PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) standards as closely as possible, unless you're writing code for an existing code base that uses some other existing standard.

Comment: Yes, I agree to following PSR but they are not that clear about assign/return.

Comment: Personally, I feel that assigning is more readable. Sure, return `$this->getFoo()` is not complicated but when you get into `return $this->isA() ? $this->doB() : $this->getC()`   which goes a few levels down, ugh.

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based and out of scope for SO. However, introducing a new variable only to return it immediately is unnecessarily verbose and obfuscates intent. Creating an additional variable opens the possibility for unwanted insertion of statements between the variable declaration and the `return` and may increase confusion for code readers.

Comment: I say you want to make things as easy as possible for yourself to write, without making it hard for others who are reading your code to understand (including your future self in 3 years when you go back over your code and remember nothing about it). Setting a variable only to return it or otherwise use it one single time does neither of these. It takes more keystrokes to write the code, and it takes slightly more thinking to understand than simply doing it in a single line. When someone reads your code and sees that variable they are automatically going to wonder where else it is being used.

Comment: i do it to make debugging inside the function easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no big difference between this two code style...

If have,the first style need to declare a variable and this is a waste of MEM, $bar is not needed.

But if you need to change the return result from the function in the future before return,the second style may be easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I find myself doing that all the time for one simple reason: Debugging.

When using a debugger it is much easier to put a break point on the return statement **after** the variable I want to analyse is filled because putting it on the line where it is filled will result in a break **before** that happened.

```
$bar = $this->otherFunction($foo);  //BREAK POINT HERE => $bar will be empty/not set
return $bar;                        //BREAK POINT HERE => $bar is filled and you can analyse it
```

Furthermore, if you are not using a debugger but still need to analyse the content of `$bar`, it is much easier to just put an echo in between these statements.

Another reason is readability. Especially when working with nested functions it is much easier to understand the code if it's not all in one line.